# Error after partitioning my SSD

Tags: high-sierra, disk-utility, partition, ssd

I recently partitioned my SSD as seen in this question [MacOS wont boot after partitioning my SSD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390688/macos-wont-boot-after-partitioning-my-ssd).
After fixing this I tried to create a new partition in the macOS Disk Utility program. I have enough space to resize my main partition in order to create a new one.
But in the end of the partitioning process I get the following error (translated to english from german; picture of error in German at the end of the question):

```
...
deactivate volumes
deactivate volume "spiele" on disk2s1
delete volumes
delete container
delete former APFS-Hard Disk
change without content type
invalid name.
action failed
```

After that it creates two partitions instead of one. For example:
I want a 200 gb partition. The operation fails and it creates two 200 gb partitions. If i want to delete them I can, but then it shows me that my main partitions new space ist 1100 gb (the SSD is 1 tb big).

I am running MacOS High Sierra on a iMac12,2. I have the rEFInd boot manager installed in order to change between Kali Linux and MacOS.

[image: Error (German)]

[image: Partition window in Disk Utility]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct, this is the same bug I had with APFS, because APFS creates a container and then fills it with virtual partitions (volumes).
I'm not sure this is the good way to do the trick but I created partitions formated as exfat for example and then format the partitions to the file system you want ?

Comment: I tried that one. It doesn't give me an error after partitioning but it creates two partitions (2x 150 gb that still wouldn't work because my SSD is only 1 tb big): [screenshot](https://imgur.com/g2iDaVe)

Comment: The Festplattendienstprogramm is quite broken, what about `diskutil list` in Terminal ?

Comment: When I type in `diskutil list` into Terminal I get the following results: [result diskutil list](https://imgur.com/TmaKSA7). Only one partition shows up, the other one not.

Comment: I think you are right and my Disk Utility program is just broken. I restarted my computer and now only one partition shows up. Thanks a lot!