# Macbook Air Can Not Start After Trying to Remove Ubuntu

Tags: macos, unix, startup, dual-boot, diskutil

I was trying to remove Ubuntu (dual boot) from my 2017 Macbook Air. Now my computer can not start successfully in either macOS or Linux. When I restart it, it now opens refind, then gnu rnu in both macOS and Linux.

I used Disk Utility when trying to remove Ubuntu. I don't completely remember what I did. However, I could not remove the partition Ubuntu uses. Then, I opened macOS in recovery mode and did some changes using diskutil. The disk now looks like this:

Can you help me fix this without losing my data? Is my data gone for good?

[image: diskutil ls]!

gpt -r show /dev/disk0 shows:
[image]

Disk utility shows:
[image]!
[image][image]
[image]!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mig0w.jpg)[image]

Edit:
Output of :
export LC_CTYPE="ASCII"
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
dd if=/dev/disk0 count=1 bs=16 skip=13108482 | vis -cw;echo

[image]

Edit:
It says resource busy when I entered the command “gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -t apfs disk0”
[image]

Comment: Hi Gizem, welcome to the community! Please edit your question and illustrate which troubleshooting steps you have performed so far, how you tried to remove ubuntu and what data you are trying to recover (Linux, macOS). Also try to choose a title that illustrates your issue.

Comment: [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390688/macos-wont-boot-after-partitioning-my-ssd) about a problem similar to yours (and its answers) might help, at least in terms of how to post your question and which details to include.

Comment: When booting into Recovery Mode and selecting "Startup Disk" from the Apple Logo in the menu bar - are any options listed? I would use another Mac or install macOS to an external drive and see if you can locate any file via Finder (or use Terminal if your savvy enough) to check what's stored on the mountable volumes.

Comment: Gizem: Edit your question and add the output from the command `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`.

Comment: I added the photos of output of the command and disk utility details

Comment: You made a mistake when entering `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII"`. If you look at the image you posted, then you will see that you entered `export LC_TYPE="ASCII" ` instead. This may have caused the `dd if=/dev/disk0 count=1 bs=16 skip=13108482 | vis -cw;echo` command to output partially useless data.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the `-f` option when entering the `gpt` commands. This option should get you passed the `resource busy` error message. If not, then try rebooting. Since you made a mistake when executing step 2, you might as well proceed from step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following steps.

1. Boot to the same Recovery Mode used in your question.
2. Enter the following commands. None of these commands alter your Mac. The commands just product diagnostic information, which may be helpful.

   ```
   sw_vers
   export LC_CTYPE="ASCII"
   diskutil unmountdisk disk0
   dd if=/dev/disk0 count=1 bs=16 skip=13108482 | vis -cw;echo
   ```

   Post the output from the above commands to your question.
3. Enter the commands given below.

   ```
   diskutil unmountdisk disk0
   gpt -f add -i 2 -b 409640 -t apfs disk0
   diskutil list internal
   ```

   If the above commands execute successfully, then the name of the APFS volume containing macOS will appear in the output from the command `diskutil list internal`. If not, then post the output from the above commands to your question, post a comment to my answer and wait for my response. Otherwise, proceed.
4. Enter the following commands. When entering the commands, use the output from the previously entered `diskutil list internal` command to replace `diskXsV` with the identifier for the `APFS Volume` containing macOS and replace `diskYsC` with the identifier for the `Apple_APFS Container` listed as the `Physical Store` for the `APFS Volume`.

   ```
   diskutil info diskXsV | grep "Disk Size"
   diskutil info diskYsC | grep "Disk Size"
   ```

   If the output from both commands match, then you are done. Otherwise, proceed.
5. Enter the following commands. When entering the commands, use the output from the previously entered `diskutil info diskXsV | grep "Disk Size"` command to replace `SizeInBlocks` with the disk size in `512-Byte-Units` for the `APFS Volume` containing macOS.

   ```
   diskutil unmountdisk disk0
   gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0
   diskutil unmountdisk disk0
   gpt -f add -i 2 -b 409640 -s SizeInBlocks -t apfs disk0
   ```

### Use of the `gpt add` Command

This section can be ignored by the OP (user [Gizem Kaya](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/436272/gizem-kaya)) . This section was added to this answer mainly to address concerns posted by user [Jean_JD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/415185/jean-jd). The `add` command for `gpt` includes the `-i`, `-b`, `-s` and `-t` command-specific options. The table below explains how the default values are determined when one or more of these options is omitted.

| Option | Default If Omitted |
| --- | --- |
| `-i` | The first partition in the table with a partition type of zero |
| `-b` | The starting sector number of the first available block of an unused disk space. |
| `-s` | The largest available size in sectors based on the starting sector number. |
| `-t` | A partition type UUID value of `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`, which is the same as the `hfs` alias. |

If the case of this answer, the command-specific option `-s` was omitted from `gpt -f add -i 2 -b 409640 -t apfs disk0` command in step 3. When the OP enters the command, the default value of `384370648` will be used for the size in sectors.

Comment: First, thank you for your response. It says resource busy when I entered the command “gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -t apfs disk0”

Comment: @David. In poin3 your gpt command is incomplete.

Comment: @Jean_JD: I am not sure what is incomplete. Can you precise? If by chance, you are referring to the omission of the `-s` option, then I can state this was deliberate and does not result in an incomplete command.

Comment: @David This command can't work `gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -t apfs disk0`. But without the size info or `gpt show disk0` it's a little hard find a solution ;-}

Comment: @Jean_JD: You are wrong. You should verify what you claim before posting false information.

Comment: @Jean_JD: I added the section titled *"Use of the `gpt add` Command"* to my answer explicitly for your benefit. Comment, if the explanation is not clear enough.

Comment: @David This works! Thank you so much for your answer. It really helped and fixed my problem 

Answer (score 0):

First, boot in internet recovery mode (cmd+alt+r at boot)
Then verify if the internal disk is always disk0

```
diskutil list internal
```

will help you.
Then from the terminal verify  if it's necessary to remove the entry 2 if present with command (**keep in mind replacing diskX with the good value**).

```
gpt -r show diskX
```

If yes

```
diskutil unmountdisk diskX
gpt remove -i 2 diskX
```

Then in all case create this entry:

```
diskutil unmountdisk diskX
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s  384370648 -t apfs diskX
```

Then you verify with :

```
diskutil list internal
```

Comment: The OP has already posted the output from `gpt -r show disk0`. So your answer instructs the OP to perform the same operations I posted in step 3 of my answer.